# How do I ensure docker containers can access host volume data after a restart?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have several Docker containers suffering from the same problem: after they're restarted or re-created, they lose access to some files in their host mounted volumes. The files are still visible within the container volume (typically `/config`) but are not recognized by the hosted application.

This seems to happen because within the container the files are created as root:root. In my host environment I do not have docker running as root - rather it runs as uid=997(docker).

I can restore their access to those files by issuing a `$ sudo chown -R :docker *` command from my host environment and restarting the container.

In the host environment (ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS), the volumes live within my user directory `/home/USER/docker` where my user is added to the docker group `sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}`

The specific containers I am using that have this issue are:

- pihole/pihole:latest
- homeassistant/home-assistant:stable
- plexinc/pms-docker
- duplicati/duplicati
- esphome/esphome

How should I change my configuration to allow docker containers to access files they've created themselves within their volumes?

Comment: I have a version of the same question wrt pihole. After a recent docker problem on my Macbook I ended up losing all my data entirely, such as DNS additions and logged data. Are you trying to persist the data externally using -v in your docker run command? Can you post how you start it?